# Why isn't this Update query working. Sequel runs it fine but it does not update the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, testing

I have a query that I am running to update Multiple tables but the same field. I have included the query below:

> UPDATE itRoomsWeek1, itRoomsWeek2, itRoomsWeek3 ,itRoomsWeek4, itRoomsWeek5, itRoomsWeek6, itRoomsWeek7, itRoomsWeek8, itRoomsWeek9, itRoomsWeek10, itRoomsWeek11, itRoomsWeek12, itRoomsWeek13, itRoomsWeek14, itRoomsWeek15, itRoomsWeek16, itRoomsWeek17, itRoomsWeek18, itRoomsWeek19, itRoomsWeek20, itRoomsWeek21, itRoomsWeek22, itRoomsWeek23, itRoomsWeek24, itRoomsWeek25, itRoomsWeek26, itRoomsWeek27, itRoomsWeek28, itRoomsWeek29, itRoomsWeek30, itRoomsWeek31, itRoomsWeek32, itRoomsWeek33, itRoomsWeek34, itRoomsWeek35, itRoomsWeek36, itRoomsWeek37, itRoomsWeek38, itRoomsWeek39, itRoomsWeek40, itRoomsWeek41, itRoomsWeek42, itRoomsWeek43, itRoomsWeek44, itRoomsWeek45, itRoomsWeek46, itRoomsWeek47, itRoomsWeek48, itRoomsWeek49, itRoomsWeek50 SET itRoomsWeek1.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek2.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek3.A5 = 'test' ,itRoomsWeek4.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek5.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek6.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek7.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek8.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek9.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek10.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek11.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek12.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek13.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek14.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek15.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek16.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek17.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek18.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek19.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek20.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek21.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek22.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek23.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek24.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek25.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek26.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek27.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek28.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek29.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek30.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek31.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek32.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek33.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek34.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek35.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek36.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek37.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek38.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek39.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek40.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek41.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek42.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek43.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek44.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek45.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek46.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek47.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek48.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek49.A5 = 'test', itRoomsWeek50.A5 = 'test' WHERE 'dayPeriod' = 'MonP1'

Comment: As written, this isn't a [tag:sequel] statement or question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update tables `itRoomsWeekxx`, column `itRoomsWeekxx.A5` where `'dayPeriod' = 'MonP1'`.

Since the strings `'dayPeriod'` and `'MonP1'` are not equal, no update can take place. I guess you meant: `WHERE dayPeriod = 'MonP1'` or `WHERE 'dayPeriod' = MonP1` (whichever is the column name that you are setting the condition on).

Besides, setting a condition that has a column name not presided by the table name... I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: Sequel suggests that dayPeriod = 'MonP1' is ambiguous if it doesn't have the '' around it, any ideas?

Comment: That would be the second part of my answer. `dayPedriod` alone does not let MySQL to uniquely decide to which table you are referring. I don't quite see how you can this except using `WHERE itRoomsWeek1.dayPeriod = 'MonP1' AND itRoomsWeek2.dayPeriod = 'MonP1' AND itRoomsWeek3.dayPeriod = 'MonP1' AND ... itRoomsWeek50.dayPeriod = 'MonP1'`. Still, not sure this will work either. Just try it.

Comment: @JoshBlakley this is really messy. I believe FDavidov suggestion will work, but why not create 1 update for each tabela?

Comment: @jfneis, I would simply use a single table with one additional field that would reflect the week number and hence the incredibly ugly update of the question would become a far simpler (and efficient one). But this is a different question of course (related to DESIGN PEST PRACTICES).

Comment: Yeap, there must be some kind of entity/value design flaw but, as you said, that's another question.

Comment: Thanks for the help chaps, it is a messy design, agreed - I want to get this way working for a short term solution. Thanks again

Comment: In the end I ran 50 querys instead of doing it this way - works better. Thanks for the help and advice guys. Appreciate it.